# Select tabs with AUI notebook (wx)

Tags: python, select, tabs, wxwidgets

I'm using wx with python and I would like to create an **AUI notebook** with tabs that contain two buttons which allow the user to **go to the next tab**, or **to the previous one**. 
Is there a function which allows to **select tabs by index**?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's in the API documentation here: http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.aui.AuiNotebook-class.html

```
notebook.SetSelection(index)
```

This took about 10 seconds to google!